# tring to get data into chart.js from Javascript or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, chart.js

I have been trying to do this for a while now. I am running a query on a database and trying to get the ressulting data into chartjs pie chart.

my table is as follows:

```
Delaytype| Delayhours
```

The delay type has an exact amout of categories.

My PHP to get this data is as follows and works:

```
<?php 
include "config.php" //database etc


If (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
echo 'failed';
}
else
{ 
$result = mysqli_($con, "SELECT Dealaytype, COUNT(1) as cnt FROM delays
GROUP BY Delaytype; ");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{


echo $row['delaytype']; //type of delay / works
echo $row['cnt']; // hours for that type of delay./ works

}
```

All the outputs work.

I have been echoing the above into a table with the id myTable.

I can access this table with Javascript via rows and cells and output value
. I cant seem to get the value into the pieData variable. The table will always be the same in the way of cells and rows so will work everytime.

the chart.js script is as follows:

```
<canvas id='buy'></canvas>

 var pieData = [ 
 {
value : my hours from php for delaytype 1 or my value from javascript,
        from mytable echoed by PHP.
color : "some color"
},
{
value : my hours from php for delaytype 2,
color : "some color"
}
];


var pieOptions = { 
segmentShowStroke : false,
animateScale : true
};
var countries = document.getElementById("buy").getContext("2d");

new Chart(countries).Pie(pieData, pieOptions);
```

The chart works with sample data in it only fails when I try to incorperate my own data.

```
previous to this I tried outputting the JSON with PHP trying to get this into the pieData . IS THIS POSSIBLE WITH 

USING json_encode ? I looked at another question in relation to this but could not get this to work
```

any help with this will be much appreciated.

```
hello Sean heres my current code cut from ide:

<!doctype html>
<?php

?>
    <head>

        <script src="chartjs/Chart.js-master/Chart.js"></script>
        <script src="chartjs/Chart.js-master/Chart.min.js"></script>
        <script src="chartjs/Chart.js-master/package.json"></script>
    </head>



    <body>
        <?php
    include "config.php";

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
echo "Failed to connect to DataBase: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
else
{


  $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT Delaytype, COUNT(1) as cnt FROM    
delays GROUP BY Delaytype; ");
echo "<table id='mytable'><th>Delay Type</th><th>Delay Hours</th>";
$pieData = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{   
   // $point =  $row['Delaytype'];
    $pieData[] = array('value' =>$row['cnt'], 'color' =>'#878BB6 ');

echo "<tr><td>".$row['Delaytype']. "</td><td>" .$row['cnt']."</td></tr> ";



  // $chart_data = array();
 // $chart_data[0]["value"] = 
 //echo "".$row['Delaytype'].",";
 //echo '"'.$row['Delaytype'].'",';
  //  $point = array($row['Delaytype'], $row['cnt']);
    //array_push($data_points,$point);        
}

// echo json_encode($data_points, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

}




    ?>
     <div id="myballs"></div>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">try this</button>
      <canvas id="buy" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
    <!-- line chart canvas element--> 


    <script>
        var y = document.getElementById('mytable').rows[1].cells            
[1].innerHTML;
        function myFunction(){
          var x = document.getElementById('myballs');
           var y = document.getElementById('mytable').rows[1].cells 
[1].innerHTML;
           var p = document.getElementById('mytable').rows[2].cells 
[1].innerHTML;

           //var c = y + p;
x.innerHTML = (y * 1) + (p * 1);       
        }



        </script>
```

```
         var pieData = <?php echo" ".json_encode($pieData).""; ?>;



       // [
         //   {
           //     value: 20 ,
             //   color:"#878BB6"

         //},
           // {
             //   value : 40,
               // color : "#4ACAB4"

           // },
            //{
              //  value : 10,
                //color : "#FF8153"

           // },
            //{
              //  value : 30,
                //color : "#FFEA88"

            //}
       // ];
        // pie chart options
        var pieOptions = {
             segmentShowStroke : false,
             animateScale : true
        };
        // get pie chart canvas
        var countries= document.getElementById("buy").getContext("2d");
        // draw pie chart
        new Chart(countries).Pie(pieData, pieOptions);

    </script>
 </body>
</html>
<?php
mysqli_close($con);
```

The javascript table stuff was me geting value etc. With this set up I get only a portion of the chart even though my values add up to more than 100 which is required for the chart to render correctly.

I have gotm rid of the duplicate JSON.

currently I have when I echo my JSON

```
[{"value":"21","Color":"#878BB6"},{"value":"99","Color":"#878BB6"}],
```

this seems correct. Could the speech marks break my chart?

It seems that the speech marks around the number for value breaks the chart.

so "value": "21" //21 needs to not be in speech marks and it works

Answer (score 0):

You can build your `var pieData` object in your php code -

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT Dealaytype, COUNT(1) as cnt FROM delays
GROUP BY Delaytype; ");

$pieData = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $pieData[] = array('value'=>$row['cnt'], 'color'=>'some color');    
}
```

and then use it in your js code

```
<canvas id='buy'></canvas>

 var pieData = <?php echo json_encode($pieData); ?>;


var pieOptions = { 
segmentShowStroke : false,
animateScale : true
};
var countries = document.getElementById("buy").getContext("2d");

new Chart(countries).Pie(pieData, pieOptions);
```

Comment: hello sean thanks for awnser. Its still not working. I echoed the jsonencode and for some reason it looks like this [{"value":"4","color": "#mycolor"}][{"value":"4","color": "#mycolor"},{"value":"11","color": "#mycolor}... The fist one is a duplicate and breaks the json

Comment: Not sure why it would duplicate your 1st value, in its own object. Can you edit your question and post what your code looks like now?

Comment: Just a min. I am getting a bit of the chart as well which is promising with the correct data labels.